# error on line 1 at column 6: XML error on PHP output

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem generating valid xml file (for rss feed) with PHP. The problem is: there is no empty character nor a linebreak or tab but the rss reader (in my case Safari) throws an error:

asdf

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");

if(!isset($_GET['searchQuery']) || $_GET['searchQuery'] == "")
{
    include_once './session_ajax.php';
    include("./include.php"); 
    require_once("./classes/myclass/myclass.class.php");
    $gmap_ajax = new myclass();
}

$query=sql_query("SELECT item_query, item_date, item_country FROM items WHERE 1 GROUP BY item_query ORDER BY item_id LIMIT 20",1);

$xml = "\n<rss version=\"2.0\">\n";
$xml .= "\t<channel>\n\t\t<title>myClass.com RSS Feed</title>\n\t\t<link>"._siteurl."feed.xml</link>\n\t\t<description>myClass.com is the largest...</description>\n\t\t<language>en-en</language>\n\t\t<pubDate>".date("r")."</pubDate>\n";

while($row=sql_fetch_array($query,1))
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $row['item_date']);
    $item_query2 = $row['item_query'];
    $item_query = str_replace(" ", "+", $row['item_query']);
    $xml .= "\t\t<item>\n\t\t\t<title>".$item_query2."</title>\n\t\t\t<link>"._siteurl."/".$item_query."/".$row['item_country']."</link>\n\t\t\t<description><![CDATA[Here is some more description]]></description>\n\t\t\t<pubDate>".date("r")."</pubDate>\n\t\t</item>\n";
}
$xml .= "\t</channel>\n</rss>";
echo trim("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
echo $xml;
?>
```

In the PHP file there is no space or anything else before the <?php tag and nothing after the ?> tag...

I'm using Adobe CS5 as editor.

In Safari as well as in every online validator I found I get this error:

```
error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

The problem is, I can see the empty space in the source code but the error is located at the "l" of the <?xml tag.

Does anybody have had this problem and has an idea or just a hint to the right direction to solve this problem?

Edit:

I've also tried to open and save it with Noteped++ and Ultraedit32 and then upload it to the server... same problem...

Comment: You shouldn't create XML by concatenating strings, use a built-in XML manipulation library like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: ok, I will give it a try and report of the result. thnx.

Comment: Just noticed you trying to write a RSS feed, you should look into [Zend_Feed_Writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.writer.html). You can add it as a standalone library to your project and that way you'll have an easy method to write valid RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Check your echo trim, do you see the php tags, the first is inside the quotes and the closing one is outside the quotes, there's your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I changed the line to echo trim('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'.'>'); but the same happens.

Comment: echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

Comment: yep, I tried it but no change... I think it is because of the stupid UTF-8 Bom but I don't know how to prevent of it... :(

Comment: Check the includes for spaces and such i tried your code without the includes and got the xml perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your output (in a text/hex editor) for whitespace.

If you cannot see anything, your problem is likely that you are generating a BOM. Use a tool like [File BOM Detector](http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm) (Windows) to scan your files (remember includes and their includes).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answeres! Specially thank you, Deebster.

The solvation was so simple:

```
include("./include.php");
```

In this file I found the empty space!

I'm so sorry that I wasted your time but if somebody else covers this problem:

Also if you're absolutly sure, control every included file twice...!

Thnx. agian and best regards to all!

Ingmar

Comment: The point still stands though; you shouldn't be building XML like this.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all my files manually, I couldn't get rid of the error. I'm using Dreamweaver as my text editor. I used the "Apply Source Formatting" function and it removed white spaces for me. That got rid of the error